# Input Data Format for RNN

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am confused how exactly to encode a sequence of data as an input to an LSTM RNN.

In a vanilla DNN, there is an input for every label.  What is the "input" in an RNN?  Doesnt it have to be a set (or sequence) of data, in order to train sequential events associated with a label?

Im confused how to encode sequential information, because it seems that there should be more than a single input associated with a given label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's draw up an example in code.

Say we have some sentences where each word in the sentence is encoded as a vector (vectors from word2vec maybe).

Suppose we want to classify each sentence into one of two class (0, 1). We might build a simple classifier like so:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# each example (of which we have a 100) is a sequence of 10 words and
# each words is encoded as 16 element vectors

X = np.random.rand(100, 10, 16) 
y = np.random.choice(1, 100)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(10, 16)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')

# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=3, batch=16)
```

Comment: `model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(10, 16))` <- missing a closing parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you have a timeseries `(X1,..,Xt)` and you want to train a predictor to predict at horizon of +1 and use sequence of length 3, your input and output will be :

```
[[X1,X2,X3]]    [X4]
[[X2,X3,X4]]    [X5]
...
[[Xt-3,Xt-2,Xt-1]] [Xt]
```

So, there are t-3 sequences, each of this sequence has length 3 and has 1 features. The dimension should be (t-3,3,1).

Answer (score 1):

> it seems that there should be more than a single input associated with a given label

Yes you are right. Actually your input need to be a 3D matrix. For example if you have n sequences, each sequence is of length m and each of your sequence data has d features the input of your RNN must be of dimension (n,m,d).

Answer (score 1):

The book (page 19) by [Graves](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Supervised-Sequence-Labelling-with-Recurrent-Neural-Graves/a97b5db17acc731ef67321832dbbaf5766153135) augments the answers with explicit dimensionalities:

Consider a length T input sequence x presented to an RNN with I input units, H hidden units, and K output units. Let $x_i^t$ be the value of input i at time t.

In each of your input sentence of words t= 1,...,T, word t has a length I embedding vector. The input on the scalar level ( $x_i^t$ ) is the i-th component of that vector.