# Setting correct input for RNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, normalization, recurrent-neural-network

In a database there are time-series data with records:

- `device` - `timestamp` - `temperature` - `min limit` - `max limit`
- `device` - `timestamp` - `temperature` - `min limit` - `max limit`
- `device` - `timestamp` - `temperature` - `min limit` - `max limit`
- ...

For every `device` there are 4 hours of time series data (with an interval of 5 minutes) before an alarm was raised and 4 hours of time series data (again with an interval of 5 minutes) that didn't raise any alarm. This graph describes better the representation of the data, for every `device`:

[image]

I need to use RNN class in python for alarm prediction. We define alarm when the `temperature` goes below the `min limit` or above the `max limit`.

After reading the official documentation from tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn), i'm having troubles understanding how to set the input to the model. Should i normalise the data beforehand or something and if yes how?

Also reading the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750133/input-data-format-for-rnn) didn't help me as well to have a clear view on how to transform my data into an acceptable format for the RNN model.

Any help on how the `X` and `Y` in `model.fit` should look like for my case?

If you see any other issue regarding this problem feel free to comment it.

PS. I have already setup `python` in `docker` with `tensorflow`, `keras` etc. in case this information helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can begin with [a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764157/6725461) that you mention in the question.

> Any help on how the X and Y in model.fit should look like for my case?

`X` should be a numpy matrix of shape `[num samples, sequence length, D]`, where `D` is a number of values per timestamp. I suppose `D=1` in your case, because you only pass temperature value.

`y` should be a vector of target values (as in the snippet). Either binary (alarm/not_alarm), or continuous (e.g. max temperature deviation). In the latter case you'd need to change sigmoid activation for something else.

> Should i normalise the data beforehand

Yes, it's essential to preprocess your raw data. I see 2 crucial things to do here:

1. Normalise temperature values with min-max or standardization ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling), [sklearn preprocessing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing)). Plus, I'd add a bit of smoothing.
2. Drop some fraction of last timestamps from all of the time-series to avoid information leak.

Finally, I'd say that this task is more complex than it seems to be. You might want to either find a good starter tutorial on time-series classification, or a course on machine learning in general. I believe you can find a better method than RNN.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you please suggest any other better method than RNN for my case?

Comment: It might be interesting to look at Discrete-time Fourier transform to preprocess the time-series.

Comment: I believe you can achieve decent results by using a simpler classifier like linear regression or SVM. As for feature engineering, I would perform normalisation + take percentiles of data (e.g. min, 5%, 10%, ..., 95%, max). Also, exponential moving average might be interesting as well as other stuff used in stock price prediction. Also, agree with @HarditSingh about DFT. In other words, feature engineering rules.

Comment: As for deep learning methods, I agree with @Drew that 1-D CNN can do well. Also, "transformer" architecture is considered superior to RNNs. But it's more complex to implement.

Comment: Thanks @roman for your input, was really valuable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should normalize your data. I would look at differencing by every day. Aka difference interval is 24hours / 5 minutes. You can also try and yearly difference but that depends on your choice in window size(remember RNNs dont do well with large windows). You may possibly want to use a log-transformation like the above user said but also this seems to be somewhat stationary so I could also see that not being needed.

For your model.fit, you are technically training the equivelant of a language model, where you predict the next output. SO your inputs will be the preciding x values and preceding normalized y values of whatever window size you choose, and your target value will be the normalized output at a given time step t. Just so you know a 1-D Conv Net is good for classification but good call on the RNN because of the temporal aspect of temperature spikes.

Once you have trained a model on the x values and normalized y values and can tell that it is actually learning (converging) then you can actually use the model.predict with the preciding x values and preciding normalized y values. Take the output and un-normalize it to get an actual temperature value or just keep the normalized value and feed it back into the model to get the time+2 prediction